# Python extend and pop on list if condition met

Tags: python

I want to filter the list moving all 0 to the end of the list leaving everything else in order.

So I have enumerated the list and on an item being equal to 0 I want to extend the list then remove the item from its index. How should I do this?

This is my code.

```
def move_zeros(array):
    for index, item in enumerate(array):
        if item == 0:
            array.extend(item, array.pop(index))
    return array
```

Comment: You're modifying the list in place. This is not a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can make two lists and append them

```
def move_zeros(array):
    l1 = [v for v in array if v != 0]
    l2 = [v for v in array if v == 0]
    return l1 + l2
```

this way, you keep the order and also, by creating new lists, you dont modify the list in place, which is usually not a good idea

What should also work instead if creating l2 with a list comprehension, just generate a zero array of length equal to the number of 0s you get from taking the difference in length of the original array and l1

```
l2 = [0] * (len(array) - len(l1))
```

Comment: `where` and not `if`?

Comment: filtering this way does remove any false value as they equal zero too

Comment: In this particular case, you don't need to traverse the list twice, you could do `l2 = [0 for _ in xrange(len(array) - len(l1))]` or similar